# How to know if running in ConEmu?

Tags: java, windows, conemu

I have a Java program, which emits ANSI escape sequences to generate colored output in a terminal. This works on Linux out of the box and it works on Windows, if the program gets executed in [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/). Now I would like to find out, if the environment is capable to display ANSI colors. On Linux I can check the `TERM` variable with `System.getenv("TERM")`. But on Windows how to find out in Java, if the program runs in a ConEmu terminal?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54747768/how-to-identify-the-terminal-emulator-being-used

Comment: See also https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-ansi.html as you may be able to use ANSI control sequences without needing ConEmu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking `System.getenv("ANSICON")` [seems](https://conemu.github.io/en/AnsiEscapeCodes.html) to be fine.